# How to call javascript function when click a button in cakephp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

```
<button type="button" id="addleetdata" class="btn btn-primary addleetdata float-left">Add</button>
```

**JS File**

```
 $("#addleetdata").click(function () {
     console.log("enter intofucn")
        startLoading();
          console.log("editvalue",$("editatri").val());
        var data = {
            'id': $("#iddata").val(),
            'solve': $("#solveid").val(),
            'problem': $("#probid").val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/monitoring/leetsave_session",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                stopLoading();
                $('#genericModalTitle').html(response.genericTitle);
                $('#genericModalBody').html(response.message);
                $('#genericModalOkButton').addClass("reloadPage");        
               $("#genericModal").modal("show");
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
```

**I Use Light Admin Theme to Develop website . So I can't call the javascript function in light admin theme using ID . So tell What is the method to call java Script Fucntion .**

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the script after the html element or you can use

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>`

and as your code;

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
     console.log("enter intofucn")
        startLoading();
          console.log("editvalue",$("editatri").val());
        var data = {
            'id': $("#iddata").val(),
            'solve': $("#solveid").val(),
            'problem': $("#probid").val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/monitoring/leetsave_session",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                stopLoading();
                $('#genericModalTitle').html(response.genericTitle);
                $('#genericModalBody').html(response.message);
                $('#genericModalOkButton').addClass("reloadPage");        
               $("#genericModal").modal("show");
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Where i have to define my function .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click",".addleetdata",function () {
 console.log("enter intofucn")
    startLoading();
      console.log("editvalue",$("editatri").val());
    var data = {
        'id': $("#iddata").val(),
        'solve': $("#solveid").val(),
        'problem': $("#probid").val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/monitoring/leetsave_session",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            stopLoading();
            $('#genericModalTitle').html(response.genericTitle);
            $('#genericModalBody').html(response.message);
            $('#genericModalOkButton').addClass("reloadPage");        
           $("#genericModal").modal("show");
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```